# Facebook's July Breaking Changes: Graph search endpoint without access token

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

We're are developing a javascript facebook app which searches for users by using the graph api.

Currently we were informed by facebook that our app is using **a graph search endpoint without an access token**. Since we are doing all FB api calls from the js-sdk we thought a valid access token is always provided. I crosschecked this and e.g. the following request is made by the sdk:
`https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=user&limit=10&offset=450&q=max&method=get&access_token=<TOKEN>&pretty=0&sdk=joey&callback=FB.__globalCallbacks.f3d041460c` As you can see the call provides a valid access_token.

Our app is requesting the following scope from the user when he wants to use our app:
`email read_friendlists read_stream user_events user_groups user_photos user_status`
Checking this token with the graph api explorer's debug method does not show any errors: The token is valid, expires in one hour and it's assigned to me (a user)[image: graph api explorer debug tool].

What are we doing wrong? I haven't found a special scope for searching for users. Thank you.

Comment: If you think it's fine just switch on the migration, some migration alerts end up being false positives.

Comment: @phwd is currect, it is just false positive to inform you if you need to make some change

Comment: ok switched it on and looks good from here ;)